# python 2.7 or 3.2(classes and instances)

Tags: python-2.7, python-3.2

I'm a beginner of python. My question is while compiling a project using python, how to make a user-input variable an attribute.

For example:

```
   class supermarket:
       num=int(input('enter a no.'))
       def __init__(self,num):
           self.ini=''
       def odd_even(self,num):
           if num%2==0:
               self.ini='even'
           else:
                self.ini='odd'

    #calling
    pallavi=supermarket()
    pallavi.(num)
```

Here, it's showing the error that there is no attribute called `num`.

What should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have numerous problems here:

1. `num = int(input(...))` assigns a *class attribute* - this code runs when the class is defined, *not* when an instance is created, and the attribute will be shared by all instances of the class;
2. Despite defining a second `num` parameter to `__init__`, you call `pallavi = supermarket()` without passing the argument;

   1. Also, why is `num` a parameter of `odd_even` - if it's an attribute, access it via `self`; and
3. `pallavi.(num)` is not correct Python syntax - attribute access syntax is `object.attr`, the parentheses are a `SyntaxError`.

I think what you want is something like:

```
class Supermarket(): # note PEP-8 naming

    # no class attributes

    def __init__(self, num):
        self.num = num # assign instance attribute
        self.ini = 'odd' if num % 2 else 'even' # don't need separate method

    @classmethod # method of the class, rather than of an instance
    def from_input(cls):
        while True:
            try:
                num = int(input('Enter a no.: ')) # try to get an integer
            except ValueError:
                print("Please enter an integer.") # require valid input
            else:
                return cls(num) # create class from user input
```

This separates out the request for user input from the actual initialisation of the instance, and would be called like:

```
>>> pallavi = Supermarket.from_input()
Enter a no.: foo
Please enter an integer.
Enter a no.: 12
>>> pallavi.num
12
>>> pallavi.ini
'even'
```

As you mention 3.2 and 2.7, note that `input` should be replaced with `raw_input` when using 2.x.

Comment: @jonrsharpe....i get it and tried to do the same way...but it still shows an error...i am putting dat code in an other question asked by me..please do answers..with regards...sriparna

Answer (score 1):

This is just a summary and leaves a lot out, but basically, your `num` should go inside the `__init__()` call as `self.num`. So:

```
class supermarket:
    def __init__(self):
        self.ini = ''
        self.num = int(input('enter a no.'))
    # etc.
```

Then to access the attribute:

```
pallavi = supermarket()
pallavi.num  # No parentheses needed
```

There's lots more to classes in Python that I don't have time to go into right now, but I'll touch on one thing: until you know what you're doing, all assignments in a class should go inside a function, not in the class definition itself. If you have a statement with a = sign in it that's in the class, not in a function (like the `num=int(input("enter a no."))` statement in your example), it's going to fail and you won't understand why.

The reason why goes into the difference between "class variables" and "instance variables", but it might be too soon for you to wrestle with that concept. Still, it might be worth taking a look at [the Python tutorial's chapter on classes](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html). If you don't understand parts of that tutorial, don't worry about it yet -- just learn a few concepts, keep on writing code, then go back later and read the tutorial again and a few more concepts may become clear to you.

Good luck!

Comment: @user3732914 - If you have a separate question, it's better to ask it as a brand-new question. StackOverflow limits comments to about 500 characters and doesn't give access to code formatting. I suggest posting a new question, then putting a link to it in the comments here.